# Protractor fails via jenkins but working on local machine

Tags: angularjs, maven, jenkins, protractor

I have a angularjs website. So, i thought of using protractor with jasmine framework for its automation rather than using selenium.

My protractor project which works completely fine on my local machine when i use:

```
mvn install
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>web-testproject</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.greengerong</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ng-protractor</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
<protractor>protractor</protractor>
    <configFile>conf.js</configFile>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>ng-protractor</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

My conf.js

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',
specs: ['./specs/bus_cases.js','./specs/recharge_cases.js'],
baseUrl: 'https://www.mywebsite.com',
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2},
},
onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
          savePath: 'target/report',
          consolidate: true,
        consolidateAll: false
        })
      );
   }
};
```

But when i have deployed the project on github and accessing it thru jenkins, i am getting error:

```
[INFO] protractor:protractor
[INFO] configFile:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Web_automation/conf.js
[INFO] Executing protractor test Suite ...
[INFO] Command:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Web_automation/conf.js
[ERROR] Run protractor test error:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "protractor": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.github.greengerong.ProtractorService.exec(ProtractorService.java:34)
    at com.github.greengerong.NgProtractor.execute(NgProtractor.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 35 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.055 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-25T22:33:00+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.greengerong:maven-ng-protractor:0.0.2:run (ng-protractor) on project web-testproject: There were exceptions when run protractor test. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "protractor": error=2, No such file or directory ->
```

Note: Locally, i run on windows. But jenkins use Linux. Is this because of environments. What changes should i do?

Comment: Have you made any changes in locally to run protractor, I mean installing or doing any setup? From the error message it is evident that it is not finding the protractor program. What ever setup required for protractor to run its needs to be done same setup in Jenkins servers too.

Comment: i think, maven is responsible for taking care of all dependencies

Comment: figured out that global npm was overriding local npm. Working now :)

Comment: document the answer for others, please!